# Connect viewmodel to model after model.tolist

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvvm

I have created a viewmodel that I need to connect to a knowledgebase model.  I have connected viewmodels to models before but in this case intellisense for result does not bring up any of the fields for knowledgebase model.  Here is the code that I am trying:

```
   public ActionResult TechSearchKnowledgebase([Optional]Guid createdById, [Optional]Guid categoryId, [Optional]Guid typeId)
        {

            var model = db.Knowledgebases.AsQueryable();

            if (createdById != Guid.Empty)
            {
                model = model.Where(k => k.CreatedById == createdById);
                ViewBag.CreatedBy = db.Users.Where(c => c.UserId == createdById).First().FullName;
            }
            if (categoryId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                model = model.Where(k => k.CategoryId == categoryId);
                ViewBag.Category = db.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryId == categoryId).First().CategoryName;
            }
            if (typeId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                model = model.Where(k => k.TypeId == typeId);
                ViewBag.Category = db.Roles.Where(c => c.RoleID == typeId).First().RoleDescription;
            }
            model=model.OrderBy(k => k.CreatedDate);
            var result=model.ToList();

            KnowledgebaseResult knowledgebaseResult = new KnowledgebaseResult();
            knowledgebaseResult.CategoryId = result.CategoryId;

            return View("TechKnowledgebaseList", result);

        }
```

As Suggested by Chris below, I installed automapper and set it up in my app start.  However, on this line:

```
List<KnowledgebaseResult> knowledgebaseResults = Mapper.Map<KnowledgebaseResult>(model.ToList());
```

That he suggested, I am getting the error, "Cannot implicitly convert knowledgebaseResult to list.

What am I missing?

Comment: Keep in mind that your result variable is a list of Knowledgebases

Comment: @avi I understand that.  Does that mean I cannot attach the two? or is there another way?

Comment: You should pick an element from that list, something like result.First(), and that element has the attribute CategoryId, the list does not have any definitions for that attribute, that is specific to your Knowledgebase object

Comment: Look at what you're telling Mapper to map your list of models to, and then read the error again.  Check the types of everything in intellisense.

Comment: You may need to specify that your data source is a list in your Map, such as Mapper.Map<List<KnowledgebaseResult>>(model.ToList());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to access a single property of a single model, though you are interacting with a list. In order to map your CategoryId, you will need to loop through each item in your list and make the association. There are libraries out there to make this mapping a little cleaner, such as AutoMapper (http://automapper.org/).

With AutoMapper, you would simply create a mapping between the two objects and pass in a data source.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Knowledgebase, KnowledgebaseResult>();
```

Place the above in  configuration file, that would get called on Application_Start.

```
List<KnowledgebaseResult> knowledgebaseResults = Mapper.Map<List<KnowledgebaseResult>>(model.ToList());
```

Now every KnowledgebaseResult will have been mapped from your original model, assuming all properties are named the same. If not, you can override the mapping by using the following syntax:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Knowledgebase, KnowledgebaseReslt>().ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.KBId));
```